# Black-white/Gray bar charts in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, data-visualization, grayscale

I have following small data:

```
         Tom  Dick  Harry  Jack
Sub                            
Maths      9    12      3    10
Science   16    40      1    10
English   12    11      4    15
French    17    15      2    15
Sports    23    19      3    15
```

I want to create a bar chart in black-white/gray colors for these data.

I can have such a figure with following code:

```
df.plot(kind='bar', colormap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, the fourth bar (Jack's) is pure white and same as background. How can I avoid this problem of last bar being pure white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the other colormaps or manually enter the color names. Alternatively you can change the background by using different style sheet such as ggplot,seabor or fivethirty eight.

```
colors=['darkgray','gray','dimgray','lightgray']
df.plot(kind='bar',color=colors )
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
 df.plot(kind='bar',colormap=plt.cm.viridis )
 plt.show()
```

[image]

Using the style sheets here:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html

```
plt.style.use('seaborn')#change the style sheets here
df.plot(kind='bar',colormap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

Here is the output looks like:
[image]

Comment: You have not read my question properly. I am already using it. The last bar is pure white. That problem has to be solved.

Comment: Second part of your answer (virdis) is not proper since I want only black-white-gray plots. Can you give example with `ggplot, seaborn or fivethirty eight`